# Real root isolation for exponential polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, exponential-polynomials

Suppose we are given an exponential polynomial $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(t)e^{\lambda_i t}
$$
where $p_i(t)$s are polynomials with algebraic coefficients and $\lambda_i$s are algebraic.

Given interval $(a,b)$, is there an algorithm to output finitely many disjoint intervals,
such that each contains exactly one positive root of $f$
in $(a,b)$, and together contain all.

Comment: It seems https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-11440-3_24 says yes.

Comment: @McLarty, that paper does not solved the general problem, here $\lambda_i$s are algebraic rather than just real.

Comment: Are the $\lambda_j$ real? Otherwise it can have infinitely many roots.

Comment: @Eremenko Not real generally. We only ask for the real roots on (a,b).