# Compare my software's representation of exponential numbers and 0?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, decidability

Suppose I have a real number
$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{\lambda_i}
$$
where $a_i,\lambda_i$s are complex algebraic numbers.

Is there an algorithm to determine whether it is greater than 0 or less than 0?

Comment: It's enough to consider the case where the $a_i$ are rational. If we have an algorithm for that case, then we simultaneously a) enumerate all the possible $\mathbf{Q}$-linear combinations, to look if any come to 0; and b) compute $x$ to more and more digits to see if we can show that it's different from 0. If the $e^{\lambda_i}$ are $\mathbf{Q}$-linearly depedent, we'll get resolution via case a; and if they're $\mathbf{Q}$-linearly independent, Baker's theorem says that we'll get resolution via case b.

Comment: Is there any theory which makes it obvious that $e^3 - e^\sqrt{7} - 6 \neq 0$?

Comment: @MattF. [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). It implies that OP's $x$ is nonzero, as long as not all $a_i$ are zero and $\lambda_i$ are distinct.

Comment: With the theorem I mention in the previous argument in mind, we know that $x$ is nonzero. Then we can determine its sign by approximating it sufficiently well so as the error bound is smaller than the absolute value of the approximation. This procedure will always succeed, but gives no bound on its running time. If you are only interested in decidability of this problem, there you have it. If you are interested in practicality of this algorithm, then you need to employ for instance Baker's bounds.

Comment: @Wojowu Sure, it is not zero. How do you know how much approximation we need? In other words, what is the precision we need for each $e^{\lambda_i}$?

Comment: @gondolf I don't know a priori how much precision I need. But I can keep taking incrementally better precision: first compute it to 1 decimal place. If we get the result, we're done, otherwise compute to 2 decimal places. If that's not enough compute to 3 decimal places, and so on. Eventually it has to work.

Comment: @ Wojowu Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't do all the computations, but it seems that the proof of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is effective, so you can bound the necessary precision. At the same time it seems that the resulting bounds would be pretty bad. Reality is probably a lot nicer than what we can prove, so just computing $x$ and hoping for the best should still be the optimal choice. (I assume that the $\gamma_i$ are given by a minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ together with a numerical approximation separating it from all conjugates).

Comment: @ Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta, Thanks, this related to another post of mine, would you please have a look? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333237/real-root-isolation-for-exponential-polynomials

Comment: I don't think this is related. Standard numerics tells you how many complex roots there are in an open domain, and you can detect sign changes on the real line. So the other question is equivalent to the problem whether we can distinguish a multiple root from a simple one. As $t$ in the other question is arbitrary real, one would need some result such as $\mathrm{tr}\deg\mathbb{Q}(t_1, \ldots, t_n, e^{t_1}, \ldots, e^{t_n})\geq n$, which is as far as I know not known.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta, Thanks. It is unclear to me that "So the other question is equivalent to the problem whether we can distinguish a multiple root from a simple one." Even if we assume that only simple roots exist on the real line. How much precision we need for detect sign changes on a very small interval? In other words, how can we know the existence of the root on a small interval?

Comment: Take a small rectangle around the real line, and use Rouche to count the roots of the function within this rectangle. Use sing changes to locate real roots. If you make the rectangles sufficiently small, you will find as many real roots in the interval as there are complex roots in a neighbourhood of the interval, and you are done. The problem is that a real double root, two real roots close to each other and two complex conjugate roots close to each other cannot be distinguished. If all roots are simple, the algorithm will terminate one way or the other, although you cannot predict when.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta, Thanks. It is unclear to me how small the rectangle should be, as we do not know the distance between two roots. Btw, How to determine the number of complex roots?